# Check size of photograph using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sap-successfactors

I want to use JavaScript with SuccessFactors to check if the size of an uploaded photo is greater than 2 MB.

I wrote the following JavaScript code, but it does not seem to be working:

```
if (context.files.length > 0) {
    for (const i = 0; i <= context.files.length - 1; i++) {
        const fsize = context.files.item(i).size;
        const file = Math.round((fsize / 1024));

        if (file >= 4096) {
            alert("File too Big, please select a file less than 4mb");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (const i = 0; ...` Why `const` here? This won't work as `i` cannot be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for of to loop through files list

```js
if (context.files.length > 0) {
          for (let file of context.files) {
            const size = Math.round(file.size / 1024);
            if (size >= 4096) {
              alert("File too Big, please select a file less than 4mb");
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Really sorry to say but This script is not working in SuccessFactors for photo validation